# v3.9.1 of Realm Object Server - Cannot Delete multiple records (lines)

Tags: realm

Up till now I have been able to delete rows of data (records) in a table with ROS.  Just installed v3.9.1 and while it lets me select multiple rows, cannot press delete key, or use delete in the menu.  If I try to right select, defaults back to one record.  I have to delete 10's or hundreds of records, cannot do it.

Comment: Is this an issue with Realm Studio?